# How to change specific URLs in Woocommerce based website?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to customize only specific URLs like this

```
https://johndoe.com/product-category/languages-cultures/
```

Should be

```
https://johndoe.com/childrens-culture-books/
```

Is there any plugin for that or some filter I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code.

```
 function custom_url_redirects() {
        /* in this array: old URLs=>new URLs  */
        $redirect_rules = array(
            array('old'=>'/product-category/languages-cultures/','new'=>'/childrens-culture-books/') 
        );
        foreach( $redirect_rules as $rule ) :
            // if URL of request matches with the one from the array, then redirect
            if( urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == $rule['old'] ) :
                wp_redirect( site_url( $rule['new'] ), 301 );
                exit();
            endif;
        endforeach;
    }


add_action('template_redirect', 'custom_url_redirects');
```

Comment: It works but leads to 404 page. Supposed to open same page. I already tried this script before posting here. Its on very popular wordpress blog website :)